# What is the meaning of method having two diamond brackets in generics?

Tags: java, generics

What is the need of having two diamond brackets in a method and  if T is not a return type why do we need this?

OR is T is something related to casting?

```
package generics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericMethodType {
    public  <T> List<T> toList(T[] parameters){ //is T something related to casting.

        List<T> list=new ArrayList<>();
        for(T t:parameters){
            list.add(t);
        }
        return list;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericMethodType gmt=new GenericMethodType();
        System.out.println(gmt.toList(new Integer[] {1,2,34,4}));
    }
}
```

Comment: <T> is the generic type indicator you are using here. By using <T> throughout the code you specify you want to use the same generic type for all those lines of code

Comment: I don't see any diamond operators here...

Comment: Hey,marko i was refereeing  in here public  <T> List<T> toList(T[] parameters..do correct me if am wrong!

Comment: @Pmleader thanks for the short yet precise answer!!1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the answer and do correct me if am wrong..

```
class ScenarioOne{
   public  <T> List<T> toList(T[] parameters){
      //some definition
   }
}
```

As,@ Pmleader said **T is the generic type indicator you are using here. By using  throughout the code you specify you want to use the same generic type for all those lines of code** and this is the precise and best answer!!!!

The  type is only valid for the method toList since it is local to the method..

Alternative solution which is applicable to any number of methods inside the class...

```
public class GenericMethodType<T> {
    public   List<T> toList(T[] parameters){
         //some definition
       }
    }
```

THIS IS AN AWESOME DAY FOR ME....AM LEARNING NEW THINGS!!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

```
public <T> List<T> toList(T[] parameters)
        ↑
//introduction of the generic type T
```

means that there is a defined generic type with name `T`, which is **valid only** for the scope of this method.

More info:

- [Generic methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Comment: ,would you mind giving a simple instance,i am kind of new to java generics and i have to submit the report to my class teacher..pls.

Comment: Read the article I've provided. There are several examples.

Answer (score 0):

The T is the generic that you are casting to in the toList method.  In this instance, I don't think it is needed.  You could get rid of all the genereics, and it would be fine for this method.